# How to import website to WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a website written in HTML5 and CSS3 and I want to use this site in WordPress. I tried to upload it like template, but it didn't work. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sirko pointed you in the right direction. WordPress relies on PHP processing and MySQL database so you cannot simply upload it to the theme folder and activate. The HTML and CSS theme will need to be modified to incorporate the core WordPress theme development, at least. It isn't that difficult if you understand how WordPress works.

If you simply want to start with converting the theme to WordPress to support pages and menus alone, it isn't so complicated. If you are very new to this, it might be a stumbling block. You really should learn the core components to making a WP theme. Good luck!

[Elegant themes walkthrough - HTML converted to WordPress](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is far too general to answer without you narrowing the scope; start with https://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page to find out how to install and run WordPress, read https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development if you want to adapt your current design to a WordPress theme. And you will need to import content, either by the database or manual entry with the WordPress editor. Read up and then come back to SO with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why people sell themes either with HTML5 and Wordpress, though seperate in nature but structural in bound.

It is a long process but simple if you have knowledge of websites:
https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites

Same as Markatledge said previously, by following the link above it can help you.